# Allowing Connections on Bitnami WAMP Stack for Windows Server 2012

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver, windows-server-2012, bitnami

I installed Bitnami WAMP on Windows Server 2012 but I am unable to get the bitnami home screen to appear. All that shows up is the stock Windows Server background as shown below. This server does not have IIS enabled, the firewall is turned off, and it is running on port 80.

[image]

I am able to get to the bitnami home page if I go to localhost on the actual VM.

Answer (score 0):

Um, yes it does! If this happens then you're running IIS. It could be a problem of network settings in the config of VMware set to share hosting IP or some other problem like you're actually running IIS on the VM. But that window is sure and true IIS.